# How to schedule the Cypress tests in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, cypress, schedule

My Cypress tests are running after every commit but I want them to run every 30 minutes. Here is my YAML file - https://pastebin.pl/view/0d56bd33. How can I manage them to run every 30 minutes(or accroding to given CRON time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> run script A after commit, but run script B after every 30 min

You can add conditions to your script. For example:

```
schedules:
- cron:  "*/30 * * * *"
  displayName: Every 30 minutes
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true
trigger:
- '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo script A
  displayName: 'script A'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')

- script: echo  script B
  displayName: 'script B'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

In this sample:

- script A will run when you push a commit and script B will be skipped.
- script B will run every 30 minutes and script A will be skipped.

Comment: I want azure to run script A after commit, but run script B after every 30 min. Your example wll run the same script after commit and 30 mins.

Comment: @AraGalstyan I can not view your screenshot in your question. Please share it again.

Comment: [Yaml file](https://pastebin.com/LQqzyRUc) - here is my yaml file that runs my tests using `npm run cy:test` script. But I want to run another script every 30 minutes too.

Comment: @AraGalstyan I updated my answer, please check if it meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! It saved me!

Comment: Glad to hear that!